# Watered-down version of the full site's design in the app

Tags: feature-request, design, android-app, ios-app

It would be really cool if a watered down (*responsive*) mobile version of the site's graphical design would be visible on the mobile app.

I just browsed a question on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com), and missed the soft yellows on the app.

How about just theming the top bar with the main colours from the site?

This would also make it clear in the UI that the user is in a different place.